# Javascript number divison

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-lambda

I have several cases that I need to cover while dividing the numbers.

**RULES:**
- Division must always return 2 decimal places
- There must be no rounding.

This is the logic that I use:

```
function divideAndReturn (totalPrice, runningTime) {
  let result;
  let totalPriceFloat = parseFloat(totalPrice).toFixed(2);
  let runningTimeNumber = parseInt(runningTime, 10); // Always a round number
  result = totalPriceFloat / runningTimeNumber; // I do not need rounding. Need exact decimals

  return result.toString().match(/^-?\d+(?:\.\d{0,2})?/)[0]; // Preserve only two decimals, avoiding rounding up.
}
```

It works as expected for the following case:

```
let totalPrice = '1000.00';
let runningTime = '6';
// result is 166.66
```

It also works for this case:

```
let totalPrice = '100.00';
let runningTime = '12';
// Returns 8.33
```

But for this case, it does not work as expected:

```
let totalPrice = '1000.00';
let runningTime = '5';
// Returns 200. Expected is 200.00
```

It seems when I divide numbers that are round, the division itself removes the **.00** decimal places

If there is a fix for my logic, please shed some light. Or if there is a better way to cover it, I am also happy.

PS. Numbers are coming from the database, and are always initially strings.

Comment: Your variable `totalPriceFloat` is a String and not a number. `toFixed()` is returning a string representing the given number using fixed-point notation.

Comment: You are correct. But, how could I have '1000.00' to be parsed and to become 1000.00?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by no rounding! By removing the "trailing" decimal digits  you are rounding down. Please explain why you want this behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recommended strategy would be to first multiply the number with 100 (if your require 3 digit after decimal then 1000 and so on). Convert the result to integer and then divide by 100.

```js
function divideAndReturn (totalPrice, runningTime) {
    let result;
    let totalPriceFloat = parseFloat(totalPrice); // no need to format anything right now
    let runningTimeNumber = parseInt(runningTime, 10); // Always a round number
    result = parseInt((totalPriceFloat * 100) / runningTimeNumber); // I do not need rounding. Need exact decimals
    result /= 100
    return result.toFixed(2) // returns a string with 2 digits after comma
}

console.log(divideAndReturn('1000.00', 6))
console.log(divideAndReturn('100.00', 12))
console.log(divideAndReturn('1000.00', 5))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding `toFixed(2)` in result line:

```
result = (totalPriceFloat / runningTimeNumber).toFixed(2);
```

Comment: I do not need rounding.

Answer (score 1):

Use `toFixed` on the result to convert number to string in required format. Converting an integer number to string will never render and digits after decimal place.

```js
function divideAndReturn (totalPrice, runningTime) {
  let totalPriceFloat = parseFloat(totalPrice);
  let runningTimeNumber = parseInt(runningTime, 10);
  let result = totalPriceFloat / runningTimeNumber;
  
  // without rounding result
  let ret = result.toFixed(3)
  return ret.substr(0, ret.length-1);
}

console.log(divideAndReturn('1000.00', '6'))
console.log(divideAndReturn('100.00', '12'))
console.log(divideAndReturn('1000.00', '5'))
```

To remove any "rounding" use `toFixed(3)` and discard last digit.

Comment: First calculation is rounding up, which I want to avoid. It returns the 166.67, instead of 166.66. However, the last one is now being shown properly.

Comment: @vedran please explain what's wrong with answer so I can understand the problem rather than edit mine

Comment: I have updated the question with the exact requirement. Thank you for the time.

Comment: You're rounding everything down which may be more wrong than rounding up

Comment: I agree, but these are the requirements that I must follow.

Comment: @VedranMaricevic Does the update satisfy your requirements?

Comment: Yes it did. I have upvoted your answer. I had two possible answers, one by multiplication with 100, and your answer. Both yield same results. I opted for the 'multiplication' one

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, your goal is to return a well-formatted string as the output of the division, regardless the result is a round number or not.

Why don't you parse the 2 inputs as numbers, make the division, and then format the output to fit with waht you need ?

```
function divideAndReturn (totalPrice, runningTime) {
    let result;
    let totalPriceFloat = parseFloat(totalPrice); // no need to format anything right now
    let runningTimeNumber = parseInt(runningTime, 10); // Always a round number
    result = totalPriceFloat / runningTimeNumber; // I do not need rounding. Need exact decimals

    return result.toFixed(2) // returns a string with 2 digits after comma
}
```

Comment: If I call toFixed(), then it rounds up. I'd need exact results, without any rounding ups.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand then. do you want to keep at least 2 decimals ? or do you want to keep exactly 2 decimals, but with no rounding ?

Comment: I always want to keep two decimals, without rounding.

Comment: what about something like  `return (Math.floor(100 * result)/100)` then ?